# java - catch value of checkbutton in a specific moment

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have a dynamic application that need to create a window interface with checkbox. The values of the checkboxes will control the next steps of the program.

So I have that interface with the button and I should select the buttons that I want then press a "RUN" button (in the moment of the choice the program must be waiting).
How can I do that?

(I cannot use a server application with html tags. It would be too easy.)

This is my code. The problem is that the program controls the values of the checkboxes before I press the RUN button. So all the button states result in FALSE.

```
public class JRadiobuttonExample extends JFrame {
private JCheckBox radioButton1;
private JCheckBox radioButton2;
private JCheckBox radioButton3;
private JLabel label;
int i, state[] =  {0,0,0,0};
JCheckBox b[]; 
static ArrayList<Boolean> check=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
JButton altervista=new JButton("RUN");
static int num;


public JCheckBox[] getB() {
    return b;
}
public void setB(JCheckBox[] b) {
    this.b = b;
}
public ArrayList<Boolean> getCheck() {
    return check;
}
public void setCheck(ArrayList<Boolean> check2) {
    check = check2;
}
public JRadiobuttonExample(int num, ArrayList<String> lbl) {
    super("JRadiobuttonExample");
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    b= new JCheckBox[num];

    CheckBoxListener ckListener = new CheckBoxListener();

    for(i=0; i<num; i++) {
        b[i] = new JCheckBox(lbl.get(i));
        b[i].addItemListener(ckListener); 
        getContentPane().add(b[i]);
    }

    setVisible(true); 

    getContentPane().add(altervista);
    getContentPane().setVisible(true);
    Ascoltatore asc=new Ascoltatore();
    altervista.addActionListener(asc);
}

class Ascoltatore extends WindowAdapter implements ActionListener{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==altervista){

        }
    }
}



public static void main(String argv[])
{
    ArrayList<String> col=new ArrayList<String>();

    col.add("hello");
    col.add("everyone");

    num=col.size();
    JRadiobuttonExample b = new JRadiobuttonExample(num,col);
    JCheckBox[] buttons=b.getB();

    for (JCheckBox c:buttons){
        check.add(c.isSelected());
    }

    System.out.println("checkbox values are:");
    for (boolean sel:check ){
        System.out.println(sel);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to show the next screen when the "RUN" button is clicked. So you should add an `ActionListener` to this button.

This listener will get the state of all the checkboxes, decide which next screen to show depending on these states, and show the appropriate next screen.

That's how event-based APIs work. You don't wait for something to happen. You register a listener to an event, and this listener is called when the event is triggered.

Comment: so the problem is in that command? altervista.addActionListener(asc);

Comment: Thanks a lot..it was a useful hint! .. the problem was in the actionListener itself... i had to call the next method not in the main code but IN the method ActionPerformed !

Comment: Yes. This method, inside the `if(e.getSource()==altervista){` (which is unnecessary), should inspect the state of the checkboxes and display the next screen.